# Security patch update

Tags: centos, security, vulnerability

If applying the latest patch(example : CESA-2019:0679 - Libssh2 Security Update - CentOS 7 x86_64) will cover the previous patch changes or we need to do it separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, CentOS patches are just new RPMs with increased version numbers. In this case, `libssh2-1.4.3-12.el7_6.2.x86_64.rpm` is installed, which contains all previously released patches as well (if CentOS lists them of course).

Comment: hello Edward, so I can also directly install patches like CESA-2019:0697 - Freerdp Security Update - CentOS 7 x86_64, CESA-2019:0710 - Python Security Update - CentOS 7 x86_64 iflidccwebap right?

Comment: @SrikanthR yes, because those patches install other RPMs and they generally don't affect eachother.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification